What's the difference between standard time related and month related DAX calendar patterns?
Link: https://www.daxpatterns.com/time-patterns/
Standard time related pattern relies on the Gregorian calendar and doesn't have any DAX code for calculations.
The custom time related pattern is same as standard time related pattern but the difference is that it's implemented using DAX code.
Both have the granularity of month.
The month related calculation pattern also seems to be similar and implemented with DAX code.
So what is the core difference between standard time related calculation and month related calculation?

According to the article, your statement above is not correct: "Standard time related pattern relies on the Gregorian calendar and doesn't have any DAX code for calculations."
The correction is as follows:
Standard time-related calculations use DAX time intelligence calculations, while Month Related calculations do not.
Some examples of time intelligence calculations for Standard time-related are:

TOTALYTD, TOTALQTD, TOTALMTD
PREVIOUSYEAR, PREVIOUSMONTH, PREVIOUSDAY
DATEADD, DATESBETWEEN

Some examples of DAX functions for Month Related calculations are:

ENDOFMONTH, STARTOFMONTH
TOTALMTD
MONTH, YEAR

Therefore, Standard uses each day of the calendar for calculations, while month uses each month of the calendar.
